# Strange WPF font issue

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, fonts, material-design-in-xaml

I'm seeing a difference in text/font quality between MainMenu and ContextMenu items in my desktop app. In the screenshot below, the first line was taken from a ContextMenu and the second line from a MainMenu (which arguably looks much better). The third line is from a ContextMenu with `TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"` applied, and while this is a slight improvement on the first it's still not as good as the MainMenu.

[image]

I've used the "Snoop" tool to confirm that font styling is the same between the main menu and context menu (size, weight, family, etc.) so I'm assuming this is a rendering quality/clear type issue?

The font family is "Roboto" (as I'm using the "[Material Design in XAML](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit)" NuGet package), and it is a .Net6 project if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that the problem can be found here:

https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/tree/master/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes

It appears that there is a custom style for the Menu which uses that font, while there is no custom style for the ContextMenu which uses a different font. Probably because styling a context menu is more complex.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be something to do with Remote Desktop. If I work on the PC locally then the ContextMenu text is fine but if access the PC via RDP then I see the font issue described above.

A bit of a weird one, and no idea why it only affected ContextMenu fonts.